# Calculating the water flow when removing a blockage

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, water, flow

A [culvert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culvert) is a construction to let a river flow under another river. At the entrance of a culvert, we use $n$ stoplogs of height $h$ to block the water from entering the culvert. Later, we remove those stoplogs one by one.

I'd like to know how to calculate how long does it take after removing a stoplog until the water column flowing over the blockage reaches a given depth $d$ and which force the flowing water has when removing a stoplog.

I guess, shortly after removing a stoplog the force and speed of water flowing into the building must be high, and then lowering down subsequently. However, I struggle to come up with a robust mathematically founded calculation of this scenario.

Comment: Is this really homework? It looks like shallow water model can be used to simulate this problem.

Comment: It's not homework, it's a question my father brought up and my own physics knowledge is restricted to electrical engineering, and I don't think it can be solved accurately by simple linear equations, so I tried my luck at stackexchange. Can you please elaborate a little bit on this "shallow water model"? Is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shallow_water_equations) right?

Comment: There is "homework-and-exercises" in your tags line. Can you show in picture what do you mean  in your problem?